# C - fopen_s cannot write to a file made by CreateFile

Tags: c, fopen, createfile

I have a main.c function and a subfunction that is called within it. In the subfunction I have used `CreateFile` to make a file. I then use `CloseHandle` to close the handle to that file. When I use `fopen_s` after that (within the subfunction) it works with both read and write modes. But if I use `fopen_s` in the main function afterwards, I can only open with read access, or else I get error code 13 - permission denied. The parameters of my CreateFile function are as follows:

```
hAppend = CreateFile(centralDataFilepath, // open central data file
                FILE_APPEND_DATA,         // open for writing
                FILE_SHARE_READ|FILE_SHARE_WRITE,     // allow multiple readers
                NULL,                     // no security
                OPEN_ALWAYS,              // open or create
                FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,    // normal file
                NULL);                    // no attr. template
```

And I use `fopen_s` as follows:

```
FILE *f2;
errno_t errorCode3 = 0;
errorCode3 = fopen_s(&f2, centralDataFilepath, "a+");
fclose(f2);
```

I don't actually know if CreateFile has anything to do with this, it seems like the permission of the file changes after I exit the subfunction? I need to be able to write to this file, would anyone know why I am getting this permission denied error, and how to fix it?

Comment: If you used `CreateFile`, why wont you use `WriteFile` function as well ?

Comment: Please don't describe your code. Show that code that works, and show the code that doesn't work. Please read this: [mcve] and this: [ask].

Answer (score 2):

As described [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z5hh6ee9.aspx):

> Files that are opened by `fopen_s` and `_wfopen_s` are not sharable.

Function failed because it can't lock file for writing. You need to use `_fsopen` instead. Try this:

```
f2 = _fsopen(centralDataFilepath, "a+", _SH_DENYNO);
```

Comment: _fsopen works when I use the tag "r" but not for updating with "r+"...still seems to be some sort of sharing issue. Any ideas?

Comment: @Chaz: I have tested this issue. First of all call `CreateFile` then call `_fsopen` "r+" on the same file and it's works fine. Please share your code, that doesn't work.